# chaining methods inside *ngIf

Tags: javascript, angular

```
project[col.field][selectedUserRole.value].join(',').length
```

If I use the above line of code inside *ngIf or inside curly braces {{}}, I am getting

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'join' of undefined

error

Comment: ```project[col.field][selectedUserRole.value]?.join(',').length```

Comment: first check the value of `project[col.field][selectedUserRole.value]` is not undefined

Comment: Be careful with optional chaining which is not compatible at all with modern browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The **safe navigation operator** (?) means that the following field is
>   optional and if **undefined**, the rest of the expression should be
>   **ignored**

```
project[col?.field][selectedUserRole?.value]?.join(',')?.length
```

[link](https://angular.io/guide/cheatsheet)

Answer (score 0):

Use safe navigation operator `(?)` like this -

```
project[col?.field][selectedUserRole?.value]?.join(',')?.length
```

> `?` or safe navigation operator checks for Null, false, undefined values while binding within the template.